# How to compensate for atmospheric attenuation of a broadband sound?

Tags: loudness, localisation, attenuation

I have bat call recordings from a microphone array, meaning i also know the 3d coordinates at which the calls were emitted.

The 3d coordinates allows me to compensate for spherical spreading. I know how to compensate for atmospheric attenuation for a single frequency sound. However, bat calls are broadband frequency modulated sweeps - how do I compensate for the differential atmospheric attenuation across multiple frequencies?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two broad approaches. The first is to make a simplifying assumptions that the sweep is best modelled as its peak frequency. Especially if the peak frequency is kind of in the 'middle' of the highest and lowest frequencies, this assumption is likely to yield decent results.

The second approach actually considers all frequencies in the sound. Here there are two methods 1) use a custom-designed finite-impulse response filter and convolve it with the call's waveform. 2) calculate the amount of atmospheric absorption expected due to distance from microphone at each frequency and 'add'(in the dB scale) this to the power spectrum. You can then calculate the RMS of the call using [Parseval's equivalence](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parseval%27s_theorem) or get back the waveform through an inverse FFT.

With either approach it is important that your recording is 'clean'. If there is a lot of reverberation or noise in the audio, all of this too will be amplified when atmospheric attenuation is compensated!

Answer (score 4):

If you are only interested in the sound pressure level you can make a third-octave spectrum of the received signal, correct all third-octave bands individually for absorption loss and then add all third-octave bands to get the sound pressure level. The sum has to be done in intensity units (µPa-squared), which is done this way, if you have the third-octave levels in dB:

$\ L_{p,rms}= 10log_{10}(\Sigma10^{L_i/10} ) $

where Li is the sound pressure level of the i'th band.

Comment: Jakob, please specify sigma. Also, why should it be third octave, and not FFT scale?

Comment: The capital `\Sigma` denotes summation over all frequency bands (should render the same as `\sum` in LaTeX). It is common to use the absorption for the one-third octave band's central (or nominal) frequency, as it (hopefully) shouldn't change much within the band.